# How can I copy a list of email recipents as actual email addresses and not names?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I got an email with multiple recipients and it's sort of like this:

> 'email1@whatever.com';'email2@whatever.com';'Joe Smith';'Sally Parker'

I want to copy the recipients to clipboard so I can paste them somewhere else, but it's copying Joe Smith and Sally Parker as names rather than actual email address.  Is there a way to just get the email addresses themselves that doesn't involve right-clicking on individual names and copying the email address manually?

Answer (score 0):

Add them as a contact. The email address will appear in the proper area. I use 2003.